# Lambda, identifiers list and const parameters: which compiler is right?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, clang, c++14

Consider the following example:

```
#include <functional>

int main() { 
    const int x = 42;
    auto fn = [&x = x]() { return x; };
    fn();
}
```

It compiles fine with *clang 3.6.2*, while it does not compile with *GCC 5.3.1*.
On the other side, the following code fails to compile with both of them:

```
#include <functional>

int main() { 
    const int x = 42;
    auto fn = [&x = x]() { x = 1; };
    fn();
}
```

Which compiler is right for the first example?

Comment: This is for pedagogical purposes, right? :)

Comment: Ahahah... No, I was trying to capture a variable that happened to be `const` in a project that is deployed on mobile, so I use actually both GCC and clang.

Comment: Bug report [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66735).

Comment: Damnit, failed to find it. Sorry.